# Connecting subnets controlled by master net

Tags: networking, router, routing, dhcp, subnet

Recently i tried to make fairly complex (for me) network, i have FFTH and very simple master router which i cannot change (it has ONT) and 3 "slave" routers.

My goal is to connect everything like in the drawing.
Separated subnets (by .0.X - .2.X) and master net (.255.X).

[image]

I have already managed to do that by connecting LAN ports of master to WAN ports of slaves and setting DHCP in every router according to my needs. But sadly it works only one way, i mean i can reach master from every slave but i want also to reach every slave from every slave (also clients if they allow that by opening ports). I know that i can connect slaves as Acces Points and disable DHCP on them and let master sort IPs but that would be random (without distinction between clients of diffrent slaves).

Whole point of avoiding APs is that master is very limited (lack of QoS, poor interface etc.) and managing whole net as client of slave. And when i switch to AP on slaves i lose many abilites of fairly good slave routers.

I need some hint how to reroute for ex. 192.168.2.1 (or 192.168.255.2) query from ex. 192.168.0.10 client to 2nd router settings page.

So my main questions are:

Is something like that possible and how?
If it is, will it also allow connection between clients of diffrent slaves?
"Slaves" are TP-LINK Archer C9. I will gladly answer questions for more details but i do not know what to mention.

Comment: What does the 'UDP' label mean? Did you mean 'UTP'?

Comment: @grawity Yeah, i was in rush and just wrote before thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is something like that possible and how? If it is, will it also allow connection between clients of diffrent slaves? "Slaves" are TP-LINK Archer C9. I will gladly answer questions for more details but i do not know what to mention.

Networks and routers don't really have a 'master/slave' relationship. But yes, it should be possible by adding simple static routes:

- 192.168.0.0/24 (192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0) via 192.168.255.0
- 192.168.1.0/24 (192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0) via 192.168.255.1
- And so on.

For performance, I would add these routes directly to the Archer routers (each one having static routes to the other two), so that they'll communicate without going through the ONT CPU.

However, for cleanliness, I would add these routes to the ONT as well, and perhaps disable NAT on all of the Archer routers (let the ONT as the edge device do all NAT'ing).

After this is done, the packets should go where they need to go. The next step is just making sure the Archer firewalls *allow them in*. In your situation, it seems like subnet separation is not the goal and you can just disable all inbound filtering (as long as it still allows you to do QoS).

Answer (score 1):

Note that for your usual home router, the router does address translation (NAT) between its "inside" and "outside". So, if this is the case, the master router won't even know what IP addresses are used on the other side of the sublevel routers. And through a NAT, you couldn't connect to the other devices from the outside without elaborate port forwarding setups, which would need to be done manually for each client device behind the subrouters.

You'd need to disable NAT on the Archers to fix that. After that, you'd need to manually configure the routes to 192.168.1.0/24 on the master router.

Also, your image seems a bit misleading. If the master router deals out addresses from 192.168.255.0/24 and the subrouters get their WAN addresses from it, those are the addresses they will use on their WAN side.

So it should be a bit more like this:

```
 uplink
  |
+---------+ 192.168.255.254                            \
| master  |-------------------------+                  |
+---------+                         |                  |
  |                                 |                  | 192.168.255.0/24
  |                                 |                  |
  | 192.168.255.1                   | 192.168.255.2    |
+-----------------+      +-----------------+           /
| subrouter #1    |      | subrouter #2    |
+-----------------+      +-----------------+
  |                                 |
 192.168.1.0/24            192.168.2.0/24
```

Comment: The static routes _are_ how the main router is told what address ranges each subrouter uses – as soon as those are configured, it can already send packets to the right subrouter. Yes, NAT should be disabled nevertheless, but the interesting thing about it is that you _can_ connect through NAT from outside, as long as you have the routes created. (Most routers will still block these packets due to firewall rules denying "WAN->LAN" access, but that's another matter.)

Comment: @grawity, hmm, yes, perhaps. Though I suppose the NATting device would then have to remember those connections to _not_ NAT the reply packets in turn. Somehow, I wouldn't trust that for every device... In any case, the way home routers are usually configured doesn't seem to fit here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to have everything on the same network segment as
defined by the master router. Otherwise you will need to define routes between
the subnets in a complicated manner.

As it seems that the problem is only to distinguish between each of the three subnets,
you could limit the DHCP allocation range of each slave so they do not overlap
but stay in the same LAN.

For example, slave 1 allocating 192.168.255.1-80, slave 2 range 81-160
and slave 3 range 161-240.

This way everything is accessible and the subnet of each computer is easily derived.

The slaves need to be connected as LAN-to-LAN (not as LAN-to-WAN).